# Hadoop mapreduce-java.io.IOException: Job failed

Tags: java, hadoop

I got the following `exception` while trying to execute `hadoop` `mapreduce` program.

> java.io.IOException: Job failed!
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:865)
>         at com.vasa.books.BookDriver.main(BookDriver.java:37)

**BookDriver.java**

```
package com.vasa.books;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat;

public class BookDriver {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JobClient client=new JobClient();
        JobConf conf=new JobConf(com.vasa.books.BookDriver.class);

        conf.setJobName("booknamefind");


        conf.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        conf.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

        conf.setMapperClass(com.vasa.books.bookmapper.class);
        conf.setReducerClass(com.vasa.books.bookreducer.class);

        conf.setInputFormat(TextInputFormat.class);
        conf.setOutputFormat(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf,new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(conf, new Path(args[1]));

        client.setConf(conf);
        try{
        JobClient.runJob(conf);
        }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

**BookMapper.java**

```
package com.vasa.books;

import java.io.IOException;  

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Writable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparable;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapReduceBase;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.OutputCollector;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Reporter;

public class BookMapper extends MapReduceBase implements Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one=new IntWritable(1);
    public void map(LongWritable _key, Text value,
            OutputCollector<Text, IntWritable> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String Tempstring=value.toString();
        String[] singlebookdata=Tempstring.split("\",\"");
        output.collect(new Text(singlebookdata[3]), one);


    }

}
```

why does that exception occur?

Comment: Can you show your given arguments?

Comment: @patrick In run configurations i have given the following arguements as input and output **BX-Books.txt out_file**

Comment: Check if the path to this file is correct. In your argument the path should be exactly where the file is stored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the JobClient source, `JobClient.runJob()` calls `JobClient.monitorAndPrintJob()` which returns a boolean.  If that boolean is false (meaning the job failed), it prints out that useless error message "something failed!" that you are seeing.

To solve this you have two options:

1 - (Faster) Check the logs.  The `RunningJob` failure info should be getting printed to the logs.

2 - If you don't know where the logs are, don't have logging enabled, or don't want to have to dig through logs, you could rewrite a bit of your code.  Instead of using `JobClient.runJob()`, I would do the equivalent of what `runJob()` is doing in your code, so that when it fails you get a useful error message.

```
  public static RunningJob myCustomRunJob(JobConf job) throws Exception {
    JobClient jc = new JobClient(job);
    RunningJob rj = jc.submitJob(job);
    if (!jc.monitorAndPrintJob(job, rj)) {
      throw new IOException("Job failed with info: " + rj.getFailureInfo());
    }
    return rj;
  }
```

My guess is the underlying problem is that either arg[0] or arg[1] (your input or output files) are not being found.

Comment: thanks for ur suggession @aguibert,finaly i found the exception was due to the way i split the text file in BookMapper.java